# mySQL Triggers PRINT & ROLLBACK

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON `agents` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE groupID int;
    SET groupID = 0;
    SET groupID = (SELECT id FROM `groups` WHERE `id` = NEW.group_id);

    IF (groupID != 0) THEN
        PRINT 'ID is ' + groupID;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The above trigger is created for checking if the foreign key ID exists in the group table.

1) How do I print error messages in mySQL?

2) ROLLBACK Function doesn't work. It gave me the following error message.
"#1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger."

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement to raise an error with custom message from the trigger.

```
...
IF (groupID != 0) THEN
  SET @msg = CONCAT('ID is ', groupID);
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
END IF;
...
```

If you want just warning message, then use SQLSTATE code starting with '01...'.

Comment: I have gotten an error message instead. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg; ROLLBACK; END IF; END' at line 10

Comment: Ohh. I see. This statement was supported in MySQL 5.5. But there is workaround - call nonexistent stored procedure, MySQL will raise the error.